# How do I add a style?

Tags: ios, swift

How would I add a style to the font?

```
golabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo" , size: 40)
```

I've tried

```
golabel.font = UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo-Thin" , size: 40)
```

but it just went straight to system font with size 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should represent the font name like following:

> golabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" , size: 40)

You can get available font names for families ('Apple SD Gothic Neo' in this example) with:

> UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName("Apple SD Gothic Neo")

For example, when print that, you will see:

> [AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold, AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin,
>   AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight, AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular,
>   AppleSDGothicNeo-Light, AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium,
>   AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold]

Comment: Did you try with the spaces like in your original post? There shouldn't be any spaces. It worked when I tried just before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You are representing the font name wrong. Use a string from this list:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202771

Comment: Apple SD Gothic Neo Thin is on the list, but it's still not working